# Convert string in format datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have this date that comes to me in the following format and it is string type

```
from datetime import datetime 

fecha_str = "2021-09-27T20:42:34.099000Z"

fecha_datetime = datetime.strptime(fecha_str,'%d del %m de %Y a las %H:%M')
```

I need to transform it into a datetime type varibale so that I can manipulate it and only show the information that is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format string you're passing to `strptime()` is for an output (ie, used with `strftime()`). The timestamp you are parsing is in UTC (the trailing 'Z'), and ISO8601 format with milliseconds.

```py
>>> fecha_str = "2021-09-27T20:42:34.099000Z"
>>> fecha_datetime = datetime.strptime(fecha_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")

>>> fecha_datetime
datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 27, 20, 42, 34, 99000)
```

Comment: I recommend firing up an REPL, importing datetime and seeing what the different format strings mentioned in https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html give you. The great thing about these format strings is that they're consistent across programming languages because they're all based on libc.

Answer (score 0):

from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = '18/09/19 01:55:19'

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')

print ("The type of the date is now",  type(date_time_obj))
print ("The date is", date_time_obj)